# Dell laptop charger - is the data pin necessary?

Tags: power-supply, charger, laptop

In a P-12 dell charger there are 3 wires - blue, white and black. From searching Google I found out that the blue is probably for communication. Now, is it necessary to use the blue wire in order to get voltage between white and black?

The reason I am asking this is because I want to make sure that my charger is indeed dead. It has no voltage between black and white, but I am wondering whether it is because the blue wire is not connected anywhere. (There is about 0.3V between white or black and blue.)

Thanks

Comment: There are reverse engineered schematics for PA-12. Is it similar to and you compare that with your P-12 model?

Comment: I didn't find a schematic specific for my model number (MGJN9), but I found some general ones, for the PA-12. (Like this one - https://320volt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/schema-circuit-dell-pa12-19v-notebook-adapter-smps-1d07012-3-34a.png). Anyway according to them the blue connector go through a DS2501. I know nothing about this chip..

Comment: The DS25010 is a small memory device that can communicate and receive power through a single wire. It is used to ensure that only authentic dell chargers are used with this laptop

Comment: You may find that without the data connection, the laptop will only run, not charge the battery, or only charge at a very low rate, or maybe even not run at all. Manufacturers often use this data connection to lock you into using their dedicated charger, giving the explanation that potentially different laptop models need to know how much power they can draw from potentially different charger models. No voltage between main terminals means dead on all the chargers I've encountered, but YMMV.

Comment: So I guess my charger is dead? Has anyone else encountered a different case?

Comment: Ok, I managed to put my hands on another charger and that charger worked on the computer which points out that the previous charger is indeed dead. Thank's to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

At last I found out that the charger is dead by trying another one, but I can't say for sure whether the blue wire is necessary. Anyway according to @
Neil_U in the comments, he has never encountered a working charger without voltage between black and white.